# Reduced relative clause (using -ing)

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

I have the following construction,

> ... a shortage of studies **that cover** the full life cycle.

I doubt if I should say

> ... a shortage of studies **covering** the full life cycle.

Or for

> ....another anchor **which shares** the same ancestor

> ...another anchor **sharing** the same ancestor

Which is the best option? In fact, I don't know when to use -ing in relative clause.

Can I always use the reduced relative clause with -ing in present or present continues cases? or it is just for present continues? Or for special cases of present?

Comment: All of them are ungrammatical;  the _it_ is a mark of Extraposition, which can't occur with a noun phrase complement -- it needs a clause.

Comment: The problems in the samples are not the relative clauses. I'd choose the *that cover* form when I was dividing very long groups of A and B, to give the reader more breath: "Blah blah blah **that cover** even more blah blah."

Comment: Marco, whatever  your Romance language is, your literal translation "it is observed" is not idiomatic in English. Also, you are asking for editing, which is not something we do here.

Comment: Originally a cross-post, now just a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335936/reduced-relative-clause-with-ing

Answer (score 2):

Both versions of the phrases are correct and natural, and have exactly the same meaning.

Using the "which/that" form is slightly more formal than the "-ing" form, so would be preferred in writing, while the "-ing" form would be preferred in speaking. However the difference is very small, and both are correct and natural in both writing and speaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extrapose a noun phrase here, so those sentences should be:

1. It is observed **that there is** a shortage of studies that cover the full life cycle.
2. It is observed **that there is** a shortage of studies covering the full life cycle.

Both of those sentences are correct, though rather wordy.