# Reduced relative clause with -ing

Tags: relative-clauses

I have the following construction,

> It is observed a shortage of studies that cover the full life cycle.

I doubt if I should say

> It is observed a shortage of studies covering the full life cycle.

Or for

> ....another anchor which shares the same ancestor
>
> ...another anchor sharing the same ancestor

Are they both correct? In fact, I don't know when to use *-ing* in relative clause.

Can I always use the reduced relative clause with *-ing* in present or present continues cases? or it is just for present continues? Or for special cases of present?